# Difference between Computer config and User config in GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory

Lets say I have two OU's one to store computer objects and the other to store User accounts. If I create a GPO in the "Computers" OU, and set user configurations, will they take effect?

Do I have to actually create a GPO in the User accounts OU and set user configurations for them to work?

Do "Computer Config" settings only apply to computers in a OU, and "User Configuration" settings only apply to user accounts in a OU?

Comment: See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287

Answer (score 9):

> Lets say I have two OU's one to store computer objects and the other to store User accounts. If I create a GPO in the "Computers" OU, and set user configurations, will they take effect?

No. I mean, unless you stored User account objects in the OU named Computers, which is weird...

User settings of a GPO will only affect user accounts that reside in the OU(s) that are in the scope of where that GPO is linked.

Computer settings will only affect computer accounts that reside in the OU(s) that are in the scope of where that GPO is linked.

You can turn off either the computer settings or user settings portion of a GPO if you wish to optimize GPO processing... but I don't see that practice often in the wild.

You could do something like:

```
Toronto (OU)
   |
   +- Users (OU)
   |
   +- Computers (OU)
```

At the Toronto OU, you could link a GPO that contains both user and computer settings that are meant to apply to all user **and** computer objects in Toronto.  You could then link a GPO to the Users OU that contains only User settings, and another GPO to the Computers OU that contains only computer settings. (Of course the assumption is you store only user account objects in the Users OU, and only computer account objects in the Computers OU.)

That is of course only an example. There are a hundred other ways to design your group policy and OU layout.

Edit: Greg Askew brings up a good point, (thank you,) and that is that you might now want to know about Group Policy lookback processing. Simply stated by [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/231287):

> You can use the Group Policy loopback feature to apply Group Policy Objects (GPOs) that depend only on which computer the user logs on to. ... This policy directs the system to apply the set of GPOs for the computer to any user who logs on to a computer affected by this policy. This policy is intended for special-use computers where you must modify the user policy based on the computer that is being used. For example, computers in public areas, in laboratories, and in classrooms.

Comment: Good answer, however since Loopback has been suggested, they will probably want to know why/when that would be used.  The prototypical examples would be Remote Desktop servers, kiosk, and other shared  computers, where it may be unknown where the user accounts reside.  In that case it may not be practical to have a higher-linked GPO to provide settings to lower containers.  In that case, using Loopback on the OU Computer GPO provides the capability to override or merge User settings, based on the computer that is being used.